# How to Convert many Lyx Windows to Tabs?

Tags: lyx

I have many Lyx windows and some tabs. I want to make all of them under the same window.

**How can I convert the Lyx windows under the same window with tabs?**

[image]

Comment: File > Open instead of clicking in the file icons ?

Comment: I don't know how to convert them if they are already opened, but you can go to Tools > Preferences > Look & Feel > Document Handling and select the option "Open documents in tabs".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Drag-Dropping is not working at least in Lyx OSx with my settings but

> Lyx > Preferences > Look & Feel > Document Handling and select the option "Open documents in tabs"

works, this is suggested by [scottkosty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307274/how-to-convert-many-lyx-windows-to-tabs#comment745652_307274) where a small difference with *"Tools > Preferences > Look & Feel > Document Handling"* with Tools instead of Lyx toolbar link. There may be a way to make the tabs/windows draggable but so far haven't found the option.

Answer (score 0):

If you drag a file, or multiple files, from the windows manager to an existing LyX window, the file(s) will open in tabs.

[This works for me on Windows 10, don't know about other OS's]